# AWS S3 lifecycle rule: only remove .JSON files in the root

Tags: amazon-s3

this is my current bucket structure:

```
- root or bucket name

  - folder 1
     - objectKey.json

  - folder 2

- objectKey.json
```

Is it possible to delete exclusively all JSON files in the root directory, without removing any prefix/sub-folder and their files (e.g. objectKey.json inside folder 1 and folder 1 itself)? I am looking to implement a lifecyle rule that will allow such logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS command-line interface (AWS CLI). Although it doesn't completely mimic UNIX-like commands, but there are workarounds:

```
aws s3 rm s3://Path/To/Root_Dir/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.json" --exclude "folder 1/*" --exclude "folder 2/*"
```

**Explanation:**
By default, all files are "included". So we first exclude everything, then include all json files, and then exclude files in folder1 and folder2. This results in deleting all json files that are not in folder 1 or folder 2.

Comment: Sorry, i must have been clearer. I am looking for a solution to be implemented as part of my lifecycle rule, so no AWS CLI. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve your goal simply by using s3 lifecycle rules. However if you are able to add a special tag to the json files under your bucket root, then you can apply lifecycle rules based on tag other than prefix.